# Анимация модели в Unity не работает

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Скачал [готовый контроллер персонажа от 3-го лица](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28647), сделал всё по инструкции
. Работает с моделью персонажа из стандартных ассетов(Ethan). Скачал 3 другие модели с сайта [mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/) в формате .fbx for unity, проделал те же действия, что и с моделью Ethan'а, персонаж вращается, но при этом нет анимации и не может ходить, то есть персонаж просто находится в стандартной T-позе. Позже заметил, что проблема в том, что все анимации помечены желтым цветом и в конце строки написано (missing!). Как это исправить? На англоязычных форумах что-то упоминают о проблемах с иерархией скелета персонажа.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте Unity есть прекрасный радел Learn, который решает большинство базовых вопросов при работе с движком.

Я рекомендую ознакомиться вам с [ним](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials) (после проектов идёт обширный список разделов с подтемами внутри).

Раздел вашей проблемы вы можете найти [тут](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/animation).

Как я понимаю, проблема у вас в том, что контроллер персонажа неверно настроен. То есть, судя по всему, в контроллере пропали ссылки на анимации.

Я рекомендую вам более подробно ознакомиться с тем что такое этот контроллер. Урок по нему можно найти, перейдя по [этой ссылке](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller?playlist=17099).

Но я настоятельно рекомендую просмотреть вам весь раздел, посвященный анимации, чтобы понять как всё устроено.

Comment: Ссылки на анимации присутствуют, проблема в том, что на стандартной модели предоставленной Standart Assets она работает, а на модели скачанной с этого самого сайта нет. Как я уже написал выше, возможны проблемы с иерархией костей. У стандартной модели Ethan и модели скачанной с сайте выше, иерархия костей немного отличается.
[скриншот иерархий](https://pp.userapi.com/c637628/v637628210/36b67/CW6jnH2VEVc.jpg)

Comment: @forge456 а что за анимации используются? Что в первом ассете шли или из Standart Assets? Или, вообще, Mixamo'вские. P.S. Mixamo и Unity очень хорошо дружат, их модели не могут иметь плохие кости

Comment: Анимации шли в комплекте ассета контроллера и при этом работают с моделью Ethan'а

Comment: Ещё вопрос: Animator Controller задействуется? Или ты просто кидаешь их на персонажа и используешь, как компонент Animation?

Comment: К модели добавляю компонент Animator в качестве контроллера выбираю тот, что шел в наборе контроллера, в нем уже настроены события срабатывания анимации. [Контроллер прикрепил к Этану](https://pp.userapi.com/c637628/v637628076/3d5ee/gL9BgHjsCN8.jpg)

Comment: Вообще нужно создавать новые контроллеры. Если контроллеры дублируются по своей структуре можно создать Overwrite Animator Controller и указать внутри контроллер Ethan'а или кого там.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56670/discussion-between-kit-scribe-and-forge456).